Remote access on 24.04 fails to connect from MS iOS RDP client
I have set remote access on in 24.04 and it works from windows and Ubuntu Remmina clients but the iOS RDP client from Microsoft just hangs. I’ve tried some other iOS client apps but the all fail to connect with assorted messages. The MS RDP client logs show this:
E|2024-08-23 19:44:26.7810 +01:00|:0 {2a665fad-f266-42a2-9379-08ea8fae0000} <0x16ceb3000> RDPSECURITYFILTER(ERR): Caught a SecFilterException during handshake: The server reported error code -1073282838. ErrorCode: InternalError
/Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdp/LegacyXPlat/Filters/SSL/SslFilter.cpp(977): OnHandshakeException()

E|2024-08-23 19:44:26.7810 +01:00|:0 {2a665fad-f266-42a2-9379-08ea8fae0000} <0x16ceb3000> RDPSECURITYFILTER(ERR): Disconnecting with disconnect reason: SSL_ERR_HANDSHAKE_FAILED   /Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdp/LegacyXPlat/Filters/SSL/SslFilter.cpp(791): DisconnectWithErrorCode()

There are no settings in the app to change any aspects of the connection security. Curiously it seems to work if I turn on remote assistance in the Ubuntu instead of remote access.
